# Why does PATCH keep adding rows instead of updating the collection?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms

I've got a gallery on the screen with a text input field. When the value of the input field changes, I want to update the selected item with the new value but PATCH just keeps adding rows to the collection. I've got similar code on other screens that's working properly.

```
Patch(colAvailableItems, galNewOrder.Selected, {Qty: Value(txtNewOrderQty.Text)} );
```

The code to create the collection is on a button on a previous screen-

```
ClearCollect(datAvailableItems,'05bGetSkusForNewOrder'.Run(radProductType.Selected.Value, ddStore.Selected.LocationID, ddWeekNum.Selected.DeliveryDate, ddWeekNum.Selected.FiscalWeek, ddWeekNum.Selected.DistPOLocationID, ddWeekNum.Selected.OrderOnDate));

ClearCollect(colAvailableItems, RenameColumns(AddColumns(datAvailableItems, "Qty", 0, "Pieces", ThisRecord.BUM * "Qty"),"BUM", "CsPk"));

Navigate(storeNewOrder);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your text input control inside the gallery control? Also, the same collection (`colAvailableItems`) is added to `items` property of gallery?

Comment: Yes, to both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
Select(Parent);
Patch(colAvailableItems, galNewOrder.Selected, {Qty: Value(txtNewOrderQty.Text)} );
```

**Documentation**: [Select function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-select)

Comment: It still just adds rows containing the value to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way but it appears to be working. I'm using UpdateIf in lieu of PATCH, like so...

```
UpdateIf( colAvailableItems, (Qty = 0 && ExternalProductID = ThisItem.ExternalProductID), { Qty: Value(galNewOrderItems.Selected.txtNewOrderQty.Text) } )
```

No new rows getting added to the collection and the data is being written to the db properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use LOOKUP in the Patch command to a unique identifier on the item.

```
Patch('DatasourceName', LookUp('DataSourceName', id = something.Selected.id), {NORMAL PATCH PARAMETERS })
```